# Several rows grouped in one row

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sum

I need a sql solution for this problem I am dealing with:

I have the following rows in a table

```
cod coda pricea priceb pricec
x1   y     20     50  
x2   y     20     50
x3   y                   60
x4   z     80
x5   z            85
x6   z                   85
```

I need to get this result in only one row considering prices are always the same by coda

```
coda pricea priceb pricec
  y     20     50    60
  z     80     85    85
```

How can I get this result with sql?
I tried to do it by `sum and group by coda` but it returns the sum of prices.

Answer (score 0):

If prices are always same for a coda value, you could use group by and use `min/max` to get it in the same row...

```
select coda
, min(pricea) pricea 
, min(priceb) priceb 
, min(pricec) pricec 
FROM table
group by coda
```